# How to build nvim to has_perl?

Tags: neovim, async

I am on macOS.  My ultimate goal is to speed up [dbext.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) and I found the page mentioned DBI which depends on `has('perl')`.

So I'd like to know how to build Neovim to have Perl enabled... Now I am using a neovim which was installed by `brew install neovim` but it seems I have to build from sources to enable Perl.

I am also interested in the way how Deoplete made my nvim `has('python3')` from 0 to 1 and didn't require a rebuild.

Last but not least.. How do other plugins achieve Async operations?  I may see if it is possible to make dbext.vim run async so I will be less mindful of its speed...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! In the future, please only ask about one issue at a time. If you have multiple issues, open them as individual questions instead of including them all in one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neovim is always compiled with all the features, so rebuilding won't help you: Perl support simply isn't included in the version of Neovim you are running. See (`:help feature-compile`, `:help nvim-features-missing`).

However, later versions of Neovim [*do* include Perl support](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22625/343), so upgrading will add this feature for you.

As for your other question about Python, not all features require a re-compile to be enabled (see `:help feature-list`). `has('python3')` returns whether the Python 3 API is *currently available*, not whether it was compiled in. (Which it was: see above.)

Asynchronous operations are performed using "jobs". See `:help job-control`.

Answer (score 3):

Update: neovim now (January 2020) supports perl as well as `has('perl')`. I update neovim very often to the latest development version, and I only noticed the feature today when running `checkhealth`. If you are using a stable version of neovim, you probably will not see support for perl yet.

[image: Output of <code>checkhealth</code> showing perl support]

Comment: Good spot! I've updated my answer to link to yours so that it's not misleading for future readers.